# How to disable a property to be indexed in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am indexing data using the default mechanism ( without passing any schema/structure ). I simply XPOST the JSON document.

I want to use :

- one single index
- various types, but not tied to the data itself

The issue I am having is that my JSON document has one particular property that has sometimes recursively nests itself. When it does, ElasticSearch errors on the data indexing PUT operation.

The content of such attribute is not important for my searches/indexing purposes. I know I can exclude it from the data, but I still want it to be stored like a NoSQL solution.

example:

{ 
  prop1      : "something",
  dirty_prop : { someprop : 123 , dirty_prop : { .... } } 
}

As it can be seen above, there is a nested inclusion, which will fail.

The question is : how to avoid the error, preserving the data. I  **presume** that removing **dirty_prop** from the indexing will allow it through. What is the simplest way to exclude it, without having to supply a complete structure ( I cannot supply a complete structure/schema because I get new attributes in my data ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say that having a JSON like that is probably not a good idea, but if you do have it and can't do anything to fix it, you can have a look at the `enabled` property that you can use for fields of type `object` in your mapping. Have a look [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/object-type/) to know more. If you say `enabled: false` that branch of the json will not be parsed nor indexed, but kept in the [`_source`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/source-field/) field as you wish.

On the other hand, I'm not 100% sure this will work, depending on how broken your json is. Of course the json parser (which uses a pull approach) needs to be able to identify the next object and continue parsing the other fields of the json.

The fact that you provide complete structure of your json makes things slightly more complex. You can use [dynamic templates](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/root-object-type/) to specify a pattern that identifies all the objects that need to be ignored and their mapping, specifying `enabled: false`.

Comment: The problem is that in order for me to specify a map for that specific property alone I might need to specify all other properties as well, and I have a schema that is dynamic, so I cannot specify a fixed template for the data. I want to avoid the creation of a map. Overall, to exclude a property, I believe I need to full template specification, which breaks my dynamic mapping requirements given my schemaless unstructured data properties.

Comment: I thought the dynamic templates addition would do the trick. You do know the name of the field that you want to ignore, don't you? That should work then without defining every field on the mapping, but of course it needs to be tested :)

Comment: +1 this comment lacks confidence, but it is correct: `enabled: false` will prevent indexing, and indexing is what's demanding the properties be consistent over all the documents of a given type.  With `enabled: false`, you can store any valid JSON.